# Trying to use -I option with g++

Tags: c++, terminal, g++, odb

I am trying to compile a source file driver.cxx and among its include files is a library called

The path to this file is `/home/terry/Downloads/libodb-2-4-0/odb/sqlite/database.hxx`

to compile it I enter the following:

```
g++ -c driver.cxx -I/home/terry/Downloads/libodb-2.4.0/odb
```

And get the message

> driver.cxx:10:35: fatal error: odb/sqlite/database.hxx: No such file
>   or directory  #include 
>                                      ^ compilation terminated.

How do I mention the path when using the -I flag for g++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the error you pasted it looks like your include command is:

```
#include "odb/sqlite/database.hxx"
```

If so, your `-I` option should be without `odb` dir (since it's already mentioned in the include):

```
-I/home/terry/Downloads/libodb-2.4.0/
```

All in all the `-I` concatenated with the include should be the exact path.

---

Meaning if you decide to include with:

```
#include "database.hxx"
```

Your `-I` option should be:

```
-I/home/terry/Downloads/libodb-2.4.0/odb/sqlite
```

Again, `-I` + include = exact path.

Answer (score 1):

Since the error message mentions 'odb' part of the path I would remove it from -I flag

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to use `database.hxx` in your `.cpp` file. Then in your `.cpp` file you should write:

```
#include "database.hxx"
```

and for compiling you should mention the path where the `.h` is present. So in your case it would be.

`-I /home/terry/Downloads/libodb-2-4-0/odb/sqlite/`

Answer (score 0):

I can see that your error mentions you use `#include <odb/sqlite/database.hxx>`. Try to change it to `#include <database.hxx>`.